# Typing lag using Vue autosave with debounce to Firestore

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, debouncing

Mounted:

```
mounted() {
    this.$fire.firestore
      .collection("blueprints")
      .doc(this.id)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        this.blueprint = snapshot.data();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, "Error here.");
      });
  },
```

Created:

```
created() {
  this.updateBlueprint = _.debounce(this.updateBlueprint, 2000);
},
```

Method:

```
async updateBlueprint() {
      await this.$fire.firestore
        .collection("blueprints")
        .doc(this.id)
        .update(this.blueprint)
        .then((res) => {
          // Success
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error("Error updating: ", err);
        });
    },
```

Template:

```
...
<Textarea
  v-model="blueprint.description"
  @input="updateBlueprint"
/>
...
```

Component:

```
<template>
  <div class="textarea">
    <textarea
      v-model="currentValue"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      ref="input"
      v-autogrow
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Any idea on why there's such a lag? It's fine for the first couple minutes as I type, but the more I type and the more data I add, the slower and slower it types. At some points, Chrome has asked me if I want to kill the page or wait until its ready. Not sure what's causing the problem here, any suggestions? This is on my local server.

**Update**: I did discover that when running `update`, when I type into the textarea, it updates the entire array instead of individual parts of the array. My data is set up like this:

```
{
title: '...',
description: '...',
track: [
  {
    title: '...',
    description: '...'
  },
  {
    title: '...',
    description: '...'
  },
  {
    title: '...',
    description: '...'
  },
  {
    title: '...',
    description: '...'
  },
  {
    title: '...',
    description: '...'
  }
]
```

Instead of updating individual items in the `track` array, its updating the entire `track` array, could that be causing the lag?

Comment: IMO I believe you should debounce with a little more ms in mind, you could try 5000ms instead. I would also make sure to check if you are making too many calls by analyzing the network tab in the dev console. Remember that update of an array can be more efficient than single individual items constantly being updated.